# Generating a 2-opt swap neighborhood from a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, swap

I am trying to write a function that takes an array, generates all of the two-swap combinations, and at each iteration will add them to an array and return an array of arrays

My current implementation:

```
function localNeighborhood(arr)
{
    var returnArray = [];

    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<arr.length-1;j++)
        {
                var newArr = arr.slice();
                var toSwap = newArr[j];
                newArr[j] = newArr[j+1];
                newArr[j+1] = toSwap;
                returnArray.push(newArr);
        }
    }
    return returnArray;
}

localNeighborhood(["1", "2", "3", "4"]);
```

The function call above **should** return an array of the following variables:

```
[2,1,3,4] // 1 swap 2
[3,2,1,4] // 1 swap 3
[4,2,3,1] // 1 swap 4
[1,3,2,4] // 2 swap 3
[1,4,3,2] // 2 swap 4
[1,2,4,3] // 3 swap 4
```

(*Ignore the // notes*, I just need an array of the above arrays)

But what my code returns is as follows

```
["2", "1", "3", "4"]
["1", "3", "2", "4"]
["1", "2", "4", "3"]
["1", "3", "2", "4"]
["1", "2", "4", "3"]
["1", "2", "4", "3"]
```

As you can see the implementation is nearly there, but something is going wrong in there somewhere. I think the nested loops and their counts are correct as we are getting six results, but the actual swap is going wrong.

I want to add to my 'returnArray' each swap. The swaps are every variable at arr[i] with every variable at arr[x] where x > i, so index 0 will swap with every variable with an index above 0, whereas the last but one element will only swap with the last one.

Help would be immensely appreciated. Thank you!

**This is a new version of my question as it was marked a duplicate of generating permutations, but I do not want to generate the permutations of the array** - I don't want the 4! = 24 permutations of the array, I would just like the 2-opt swaps of variables array[i] swap array[x] where x > i. Generating permutations is the easy way but for longer arrays takes far too much time and Chrome crashes. Though my example is an array of 4 elements, the input array could be longer.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the end value of the outer loop and start the inner loop with the incremented vaule of `i`.

This proposal uses no check for same array as the last swapping, because only existing indices are used for swapping.

```js
function swap(array) {
    var i, j,
        temp,
        result = [];

    for (i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            temp = array.slice();
            temp[i] = array[j];
            temp[j] = array[i];
            result.push(temp);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    result = swap(array);

console.log(result.map(a => JSON.stringify(a)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't normally advise recursion in JS however just for fun you may implement an Haskellesque pattern matching by using spread and rest operators through destructuring and may come up with something like;

```js
var doSomething = ([x,...xs]) => xs.length ? xs.map((e,i) => [e].concat(Object.assign([],xs,{[i]:x})))
                                               .concat(doSomething(xs).map(sa => [x].concat(sa)))
                                           : [];

console.log(JSON.stringify(doSomething([1,2,3,4])));
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out! Please see below on how to generate a 2-opt swap for a JavaScript array

```
function localNeighborhood(arr)
{
    var returnArray = [];

    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<arr.length;j++)
        {
                var newArr = arr.slice();
                var toSwap = newArr[i];
                newArr[i] = newArr[j];
                newArr[j] = toSwap;
                if(arr.toString() != newArr.toString())
                {
                    returnArray.push(newArr);
                }
        }
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Then calling the following:

```
localNeighborhood(["1", "2", "3", "4"]);
```

Will return these values:

```
["2", "1", "3", "4"]
["3", "2", "1", "4"]
["4", "2", "3", "1"]
["1", "3", "2", "4"]
["1", "4", "3", "2"]
["1", "2", "4", "3"]
```

This is perfect for solving problems such as the Travelling Salesman Problem through a 2-opt edge swap, if your tour is represented as an array like above, the function will generate all of the two-opt edge swaps for you to evaluate and store the best one for the current iteration.

Hope this helps!